# How to receive EventGrid Events in the POST method of JAVA

Tags: java, spring, azure-eventgrid, azure-java-sdk

I was trying to see if we need to set the Header(similar to the ones in the picture below) to send the data to the HTTP POST endpoint of Java to read the data in the EventGrid Schema sent by Event Grid or if there is any other way the Java POST method could read these?

Taking the example below where the C# endpoint is reading the event grid events from Request.Body:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-event-quickstart-portal
GitHub Link:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-event-grid-viewer/blob/main/viewer/Controllers/UpdatesController.cs

What would be the effective way to implement the

```
  private async Task<IActionResult> HandleGridEvents(string jsonContent)
```

method in the link above in Java?

[image]

Comment: Implement an endpoint to receive custom HTTP request. Is this what you want?